# Vs Service Interface

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, oop

I don't know whether this question is already there or not on Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow here is the situation:

1. I am writing a back-end application (in Java)
2. I have a rest API (Soppose that searches some items in database)
3. The search API invokes several different different services to reach to final result.

Now, Because this API goes to various services, those service interfaces already been defined, what methods those expose, which parameters to accept etc. etc. So now This takes a lot of time to complete this task (whole task of searching, going to verious services).

My confusion is, If I change some service invocations here, or change the Design/data (which service holding which data), then I may get the results faster. My search algorithm will become better in that case, but **the Design will NOT be very good and clean as it is now**.

So Whether we do the design part before or we should first think about the algorithm complexity that we are going to implement? Which is more important in high load application. Is it good to compromise with the application design part for getting the results faster?

What are the best practices for these types of scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is - if your the search operation is too crucial for your system, you can drive the design decision for your services keeping in mind the search API's efficiency. But, if there are other operations other than the search API and the new design will affect the performance of those operations, then you need to consider before re-design.

You should stick with some constraints to define microservices boundaries. Please read [Microservice boundaries: five characteristics to guide your design](https://codeburst.io/microservice-boundaries-five-characteristics-to-guide-your-design-89312b65cc27).

Also you should design services not only for operations simplicity but in a way that if one of the services fails, the whole system should be able to serve and can be changed, scaled and deployed independently. Please check [Vertical Slicing on Microservices](http://www.dhrubo.net/2017/04/microservices-vertical-slicing.html)